# Printing with structure

Tags: c

This is a program for preparing simple student marklist:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define SIZE 50

struct mark {
  char name[50];
  float marks[5];
};

int main() {

  int sn, subn, i, j;

  printf ("\n Enter Number of Students : ");
  scanf ("%d",&sn);

  printf ("\n");

  struct mark n[SIZE];

  for (i = 1; i < sn + 1; ++i){
    printf (" Enter Name of Student %d : ",i);
    scanf ("%s",&n[i - 1].name);

    for (j = 1; j < 6; ++j){
      printf (" Enter Marks of Subject %d : ",j);
      scanf ("%f",&n[i - 1].marks[j - 1]);
    }
  }

  printf ("\n\n ------------------------------------------------------------------- \n\n");

  printf (" Student Name \t\t Sub 1\t Sub 2\t Sub 3\t Sub 4\t Sub 5");

  printf ("\n --------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

  for (i = 0; i < sn; ++i) {
    printf ("\n   %s \t\t ",n[i].name);

    for (j = 0; j < subn; ++j){
      printf ("%d \t",n[i].marks[j]); /* Problem with this line. Prints integers like -24611 etc.*/
    }
  }

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

When I get to the marked line, the program prints some numbers like -241563 etc.

What's wrong? Is it something with the structure? First it prints five 0 when it would have printed the marks. And then prints the integers like -241563. Please help.

Comment: `marks` is an array of `float`s. Use %f.

Answer (score 0):

The format string in `printf` does not match the argument list

Change:

```
  printf("%d \t", n[i].marks[j]);
```

to

```
  printf("%f \t", n[i].marks[j]);
```

Comment: Fixed it. Problem was i put %d instead of %f and also used 'subn' which had no work in this program

Comment: @AnikShahriar actually `subn` has never been initialized. Didn't your comopiler warn you ?

Comment: Nope it didn't.